# Existe alguma maneira de testar uma rota usando o PHP unit no Laravel?

Tags: laravel, testes-de-unidade, phpunit

Gosto muito de criar usar o `PHPunit` para criar testes unitários para minhas bibliotecas.

Sempre, antes de fazer o `git commit`, executo-o para ver se alguma alteração afetou aquilo que anteriormente já estava funcionando.

Eu gostaria de também poder testar rota por rota no `Laravel`,de um jeito semelhante ao `PHPUnit`, para que, quando fizer alguma alteração, eu possa já ter testes automatizados, ao invés de sair testando rota por rota, pelo navegador.

Como eu poderia fazer isso no `Laravel`?

Comment: Se é que eu entendi direito, o tal "teste de rota" que você se refere, se chama teste funcional, ou teste de aceitação(Não tenho muita certeza) você pode pesquisar a definição desses dois... Existe outras ferramentas que são indicados para esse tipo de teste. Recomento esta aqui, que é baseada no PHPUnit: http://codeception.com/

Comment: @user5978 você é o cara! vou dar uma olhada em casa nisso aí, mano!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No Laravel especificamente você pode usar as classes do namespace/pacote `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\` (fonte: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/testing)

> Note que o exemplo aqui é para Laravel5.2

Dentro da pasta `tests` que fica dentro da sua aplicação Laravel deve conter dois arquivos, o `TestCase.php` que é a "base" para criar os seus testes e o `ExampleTest.php` que você pode usar para criar seus testes ou então pode criar um novo arquivo, todos arquivos que criar devem terminar com `Test.php`, por exemplo:

- `FooTest.php`
- `BarTest.php`
- `BazTest.php`

Um exemplo:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testBasicExample()
    {
        $this->visit('/')
             ->see('Laravel 5')
             ->dontSee('Teste');
    }
}
```

- O método `visit` faz uma requisição GET na aplicação.
- O método `see` afirma que devemos ver na resposta da aplicação o texto `Laravel 5`
- O método `dontSee` afirma que não devemos ver resposta o texto `Teste` na resposta da aplicação

Para obter todas as rotas você pode usar o método `->getRoutes();` da classe `\Illuminate\Routing\Router` que vai retornar um objeto do tipo: [`\Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection`](https://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.html) e depois você vai poder usar o `getRoutesByMethod` (ou `getRoutes`) que é um método da classe `RouteCollection` e com isso poderá criar o seu teste.

No seu teste deve ficar algo como:

```
$routeCollection = Route::getRoutes();

foreach ($routeCollection as $value) {
    $this->visit($value->getPath());
}
```

> É apenas uma sugestão, por favor não deixe de criticar se encontrou alguma falha, eu não usei ainda, só segui a documentação.